# Access parent object without referencing it

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I've bumped into a refcount problem where objects don't get deleted because there's an "unnecessary" member referencing the parent (circular reference).

Here's the shortened version:

```
class User(object):
    __slots__ = ("driver")
    def __init__(self, *params):
        self.driver = getDriverType(params)()
        self.driver.parent = self

    def getFancyObject(self):
        return FancyObject(self)

class Driver(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent = None
    def specialCode(self):
        self.parent.getFancyObject()
        ...
        # driver-specific code doing something with fancyObject
```

In order to do driver-specific stuff, I still need the advanced functionality only the parent provides (again, through driver-provided functions). I could do without the FancyObject instance, but then a lot more code would have to be typed.

Of course, creating this reference to parent prevents both parent and driver to be destroyed which not only takes up RAM in the Python VM, but also hardware resources this driver handles. Sunce every instance of `User` remains, this quickly escalates to unresponsive app and out-of-memory exceptions.

Needless to say, the `__slots__` in `User` class prevent weakref.ref to be created on that class.

Admittedly, I'm so wrapped into this issue I just can't see a nice Pythonic solution to this issue.

How can I achieve the desired functionality without creating references that prevent object gc?

Comment: Can you delete the reference to the parent after retrieving the "fancy object"?

Comment: no, as I don't know when the functionality requiring FancyObject will be called. It can be called frequently or not at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact an object is defined with `__slots__` does not preclude the ability to create a weak reference to that object. But it does mean you need to explicitly define the `__weakref__` attribute:

```
class User:
    __slots__ = ('driver','__weakref__')
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = Driver()
        self.driver.parent = weakref.ref(self) # or weakref.proxy(self)
    def __del__(self):
        print('user deleted')

class Driver:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent = None
    def __del__(self):
        print('driver deleted')

>>> u = User()
>>> del u
user deleted
driver deleted
```

Comment: IMO it'll be nicer to use a `weakref.proxy` instead of a `ref`. The proxy behaves like the real object without specific dereferencing.

Comment: the use of `ref` was an example (based on the OP's comment)... the point is you need to explicitly create the `__weakref__` slot (whether you use `ref` or `proxy`).

Comment: Thanks, and I agree with proxy vs ref, lazy1 :)